# Simple many-to-many select query in JPQL and embeddable key

Tags: java, database, jpql

I have this model, just two entities, one embeddable entity for a key and one entity in which that key is as an id field.

I would like to know, how to write as simple query as "give me all functions of a person with id 5" of "give me all function of a person with name Somebody".

I do not understand how to access these info when there is that embeddable key ...

I hesitate to rewrite my model because I would have to rewrite tons of stuff around the code.

How do I even delete some stuff from that association table? I just really do not know which "way" I should take to attack that problem.

Thank you for the hint guys

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;
    // .. getters and setters

@Entity
@Table(name = "FUNC")
public class Function {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "function_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    // .. getters and setter

@Embeddable
public class PersonFunctionPK {

    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Long personId;

    @Column(name = "function_id")
    private Long functionId;

    public PersonFunctionPK() {
    }

    PersonFunctionPK(Long personId, Long functionId) {
        this.personId = personId;
        this.functionId = functionId;
    }
    // .. getters and setter

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON_FUNC")
public class PersonFunction {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected PersonFunctionPK personFunctionPK;

    public PersonFunction() {}

    public PersonFunction(PersonFunctionPK personFunctionPK) {
        this.personFunctionPK = personFunctionPK;
    }

    public PersonFunction(Long personId, Long functionId) {
        this.personFunctionPK = new PersonFunctionPK(personId, functionId);
    }

    // .. getters and setter for personFunctionPK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be mapping these as single standalone entities. If you map the relationships between entities then you should be able to do most of your queries by simply calling a get method (no jpql required)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "persons", cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    private Collection<Function> functions;

    // .. getters and setters

@Entity
@Table(name = "FUNC")
public class Function {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "function_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_FUNC",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "function_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}, 
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}) 
    private Collection<Person> persons;

    // .. getters and setter
```

Now if you get a person with id of 5 you can call a simple getter to get the functions for just this person. You might still need to use JPQL if say you wanted a collection of functions assigned to all people called Stefan. You still need the @ManyToMany mapped though because in JPQL you specify the object relationships (not the underlying DB)

```
select distinct f from Function f inner join f.persons p where p.name = "Stefan"
```

I haven't tested any of this code but it should be roughly right.